# Interact with devices services (HTML 5 vs Silverlight)

Tags: html, silverlight, upnp

We want to start new Web-base project.We need to provide interaction with devices services such as Calendar, Contacts, Camera, etc.(Possibly with upnp)
In a real project from Silverlight and HTML5 which one is a better choice?
Why?

Comment: This question is both broad and opinion-based. Either would be a good reason to close it. If it can be edited to narrow down to specific objective comparisons between options, it would be constructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sake of simplicity I would use Silverlight. It is much easier to access a USB Webcamera via Silverlight over HTML5. On the flip side if your using an IP camera I would go with HTML5.

It's honestly up to you. I would go with whichever framework you are more familiar with. But keep in mine whatever you can do in HTML5 you **CAN** do (and more) in Silverlight. Silverlight has more power than HTML5 because you get all the HTML features as well as the Silverlight features. In HTML you only get HTML

Comment: While the above is true, it should be noted that Silverlight is deprecated.  Development has ceased and it does not work in Chrome out of the box.